# FoxPro - character limit on column names with INTO TABLE

Tags: foxpro, visual-foxpro

One of our systems is still running on a Visual FoxPro database. It's the bane of my life.

While investigating a recent error, I discovered it was being caused by a misnamed column. The original DB has a table called `SELECTIONS` with a column called `mediumValue`, which is eleven characters long. The error was being caused by another table based on that data having the column renamed to `mediumValu`.

The source of the problem appears to be this statement:

```
SET DELETED ON
SELECT selections.*;
 FROM ;
     SELECTIONS;
 WHERE 
//criteria
 INTO TABLE Result.dbf
```

If you just run the select without the `INTO TABLE`, the column appears named as `mediumValue`. But with the `INTO TABLE`, the resulting `Result.dbf` table has the column named as `mediumValu`.

Am I right in thinking this is some sort of inbuilt truncation, and is it documented anywhere? Is there any sort of setting I can override to fix it?

Comment: The .DBF format has a restriction of 10 characters on field (column) names, and AFAIK it's a restriction of the file format and can't be changed.

Comment: The restriction is described here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3kfd3hw9(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct on the truncation to the external table.  In VFP, a database container (.dbc) allows tables to have column names longer than the default max of 10 characters for a "free" table (ie: not associated with a database).  So, the original 11 characters is probably valid because it IS part of a database container.

Now, if you are doing this for some temporary processing to work with the data in another area of the program, you can always select

```
INTO CURSOR C_MyTestResults readwrite
```

This way, it is an In-memory table and WILL retain the full column name lengths.  The READWRITE clause will allow you to make changes to the cursor data while you are working just as if it was a table itself too.

I like to use "C_" as a prefix to the table result alias so I know that it is a "CURSOR" and not a production table, and know I am not messing around with production data depending on the task at hand.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to execute the vfp command `select ..into table..`, with more than 10 characters fields names, you must use the `database` clause.

For example:

```
SELECT selections.*;
 FROM ;
     SELECTIONS;
 WHERE 
//criteria
 INTO TABLE Result.dbf  DATABASE dbUser
```

If you don't have a databse for that (dbUser.dbc) you can create it:

```
create database c:\dbUser
```